# A problem about ring of polynomials over a field

Tags: polynomials

For $K$ is an infinite field and $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ $\in K[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ . Prove that If $f(a)=0 $ for any $a \in K^n$ then $f=0$.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, this is straightforward since a nonzero polynomial in a single variable has only finitely many roots.

Suppose $n>1$. Suppose $f\neq 0$. If $f$ is constant, it trivially doesn't vanish everywhere. So suppose $f$ is nonconstant, and assume without loss of generality the variable $X_1$ occurs in $f$. Write your $f$ as $f=a_mX_1^m+\cdots+a_1X_1+a_0$ for $a_i\in K[X_2,\dots,X_n]$, with $a_m\neq 0$. Since $a_m$ is a polynomial in fewer variables, by induction, there is a point $(c_2,\dots,c_n)\in K^{n-1}$ such that $a_m(c_2,\dots,c_n)\neq 0$. Fixing this point, we have
$$
g(X_1)=f(X_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)\in K[X_1].
$$
This is a nonzero polynomial in a single variable, so we can find $c_1\in K$ such that $0\neq g(c_1)=f(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)$, so $f$ doesn't vanish on $K^n$.

Comment: thanks a lot @Ben West . It's very nice